# Angular nested menu

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Task:**
The nested menu is split into two columns on level 0. For example, if Level 0 has a submenu with more than 3 children split these two-two columns if not show the single column.

```
    var example_data = [{
    level: 0,
    text: 'Business',
    url: 'http://google.de',
    submenu: [{
        level: 1,
        text: 'link 1',
        url: 'http://google.de',
        submenu: [{
            level: 2,
            text: 'link 1',
            url: 'http://google.de'
        }, {
            level: 2,
            text: 'link 2',
            url: 'http://google.de',
            submenu: [{
                level: 2,
                text: 'link 2 1',
                url: 'http://google.de'
            }, {
                level: 2,
                text: 'link 2 2',
                url: 'http://google.de'
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

**expected result**
is recursive `ng-repeat` plus splitting on level 0 submenu

full example in here [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/w62EGwdkMJbLjHVjBZhN?p=preview)

Comment: Plnkr is updated and problem is solved.Cheers